# Search Phone Numbers and String globally in Servicenow CRM not working

Tags: crm, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Searching using Global Text Search
[image: global search made here]

---

No Record found even though the record is there in the contacts custom table.
[image: Not returning result even though the record is there in list]

---

**Found the solution. Added the custom table into the Search Groups and now it is working.**
[image: search result]
Global search is not working for contacts in ServiceNow CRM. Do we need to configure anything to workout the phone number or name search globally?. I am new to Servicenow, Please help me how to enable this to perform global search.

Comment: Please share how you are trying to do it. So that kit will help to narrow down the issue. Btw there is a configuration for Global Text Search in ServiceNow.

Comment: Added images in description.I am trying to search Phone Number and String Globally.Please tell what is the configuration i need to do.

Comment: What configuration do you have in your `Global Text Search` in ServiceNOW?

Comment: I have seen the configuration here -->System properties->Global text search 
 #1.Enable Global Text Search:   Yes                                                                                                                                                                                     #2.List of roles (comma-separated) that can use the Global Text Search capability:   itil,text_search_admin,admin

Comment: #3.List of tables (comma-separated) that will not appear as options when setting up Global Text Search tables:
sys_audit,sys_event,ecc_queue,ecc_event,syslog,syslog_transaction,sys_journal_field,sys_audit_relation,ecc_agent_log,ecc_mi_result,sysrule_escalate_history,sys_user_token,sys_time_dimension,sys_attachment_doc,sys_audit_delete
#4.Query method for global text search:Simple Query

Comment: Which ServiceNow release you are using? (e.g. Jakarta, London, New York)?

Comment: My serviceNow Release is London

Comment: After adding the tables in search group ,now i am able to get results with text and phone number  in Global search in CRM UI. But these search are working fine only with standard fields not with custom phone fields.Also i enabled text search in text index for the custom field. 
https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b2553f1ddba75b04a8562926ca96191b

Comment: Also i don't know how to do this with REST API?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? Do you want to know how to search using REST API?

There is no such API available at the moment to make a global text search. You can use tables api or scripted rest api specifically

Comment: I want to achieve CRM behavior via REST API. So there is no REST API available for global search and using tables API we can search against one particular table like https://dev55738.service-now.com/api/now/table/customer_account?sysparm_query=nameSTARTSWITHAcc. Am i right ?

Comment: the contacts table which i added in search group is not custom table ,it is standard table customer_contact.

Comment: Yes you can use table api to search in any table you want like the one you have shared in the comment. Searching a record with name starts with Acc in customer_account table